# Create a hashmap inside a class?

Tags: java, class, hashmap

I want to create a Hashmap inside a class. For example, I have a class in Java that looks like so:

```
public class test{
  public static class testClass{
    HashMap<String, Integer> data;
    testClass left;
    testClass right;

    testClass(){
      left = null;
      right = null;
      data.put("", -1); // Exception here 
    }
  }
  public static void main(String []args){
    testClass database = new testClass(); //Throws an exception here also
  }
}
```

And as you can see from the code above, there is an exception thrown where I try to create the class and when I try to initialize the hashmap. However, from all the examples I've seen, I noticed that you need to create memory for the HashMap using the `new` keyword. As a result, I'm wondering, is this possible to do? If so, is there a way to fix these exceptions? If anyone could help me out that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using proper initialization? where is your `()` in `new testClass;`? Also where is the return type of method `trie()`?

Comment: Your code might cause the compiler to explode. Please go through a [basic tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: where do u think that ur data would be store if u don't has a memory for it.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to initialize your `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Apart from that, your code is messy and has many problems:

1. Bad naming conventions.
2. Incorrect way of creating instances.
3. Your class serves no apparent purpose.
4. Placing the array brackets with the name, instead of type, is discouraged.

If you want to learn how to improve on all of those, read the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Ah okay.Would I do this in the beginning of declaring the variable or within the constructor? The code is just an example.

Comment: Where don't you see the constructor?

Comment: @RohitJain He edited his question :P There wasn't a constructor before he edited.

Comment: @JoshM Oh! Didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't create a instance of `HashMap`, You just declared a variable type of `HashMap`, you need to initialize that `HashMap` inorder to use it, like

`HashMap<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

You can declare and initialize that `HashMap` in the same line, or if you have a constructor, you can initialize it inside the constructor.

Corrected version of you faulty class.

```
public class test{
  public static class testClass{
    HashMap<String, Integer> data;
    testClass left;
    testClass right;

    testClass(){
      left = null;
      right = null;
      data = new HasMap<String, Integer>();
      data.put("", -1);
    }
  }
  public static void main(String []args){
    testClass database = new testClass();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's one of the 10 problems he have there.

Comment: Would I do so in the beginning of declaring the variable or in the constructor?

Comment: @user1871869 You have **no** constructor.